# Ubuntu Brightness issue HP VICTUS ryzen 7 GRTX

Tags: boot, dual-boot, screen, brightness

have an hp victus 15 gaming laptop (dual gpu) and as soon as I booted up linux the screen went dim. BIOS menu and hp victus symbol remains bright every time I boot it up until the distro icon pops up, then the screen goes dim. Have tried multiple distros (currently using ubuntu 22.10). The buttons and /sys/class/brightness folder both work changing that value, and the only brightness variability i get is when the slider is full it gets slightly dimmer and when it emptys it gets slightly brighter. I've spent a lot of time trying to debug this issue, I have tried many different versions of different drivers, different kernels, different distros, putting things in my /etc/default/grub file, as well as updating my BIOS. I am desperate for some help in troubleshooting and resolving this issue. All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The BIOS has screen brightness settings. It seems that the brightness setting is different in BIOS and in OS. That is why the screen brightness changes when OS is loaded. You can try searching for brightness setting in BIOS and keep it same as the OS